# Should there be a different tag for System-Modeling?

Tags: discussion, tagging

So far, there has only been the tag [[tag:system-modeler]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/system-modeler/info) to be assigned to questions regarding [Wolfram's System Modeler (WSM)](http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/). But as of Version 11.3.0 `SystemModel` is a Wolfram Language data type/entity and the [*system modeling functionality*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SystemModelingOverview.html) of [Modelica](https://www.modelica.org/), the declarative modeling language used by WSM, has been integrated into the Wolfram Language.

I have created a new tag [system-modeling](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-modeling) to more clearly separate questions regarding the system modeling functionality integrated into the language from questions regarding the WSM and its interaction with Mathematica/WL.

What do you think:  Should there be a separate tag [system-modeling](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-modeling)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If [system-modeler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-modeler) questions tend to revolve mostly around WSM, I see some value in keeping a single tag, but if Wolfram keeps pushing integration in Mathematica and system modeling/Modelica inside Mathematica becomes its own thing, I think the split is a sound idea. I would additionally suggest to change the tag [system-modeler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-modeler) to [wolfram-system-modeler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-system-modeler) or equivalent to further disambiguate the two.

Comment: That sounds very reasonable to me; I would prefer [tag:wolfram-system-modeler] as well.